# prefix with append in prolog- how does it work?

Tags: prolog

how does the following code for prefix in Prolog work?

prefix supposed to return the prefix of a list.
for example:

```
?-prefix([1,2,3],X)
```

(i am not sure if it should be written as the opposite: prefix(X, [1,2,3]) 
will return [], then [1], then [1,2]...

the code:

```
prefix(Xs,Ys):- append(Xs,_,Ys).

append([],Xs,Xs).
append([X|Xs],Ys,[X,Zs]):-append(Xs,Ys,Zs).
```

could anyone run an example ? (the append just adds two strings)

Comment: Variables must begin with upper case, or they're not variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to write the predicate would be:

```
prefix(Xs, Ys) :- append(Ys, _, Xs).
```

What this says is *`Ys` is a prefix of `Xs` if `Ys` appended with some other list (I don't care what it is) is `Xs`*.

Now in prolog, when you issue a query, such as `append`, and the predicate is defined relationally, it will attempt to find all solutions that make the query TRUE. If I have the query, `append(Ys, _, [1,2,3])`, prolog can make this true by instantiating `Ys` with `[]` and `_` with `[1,2,3]` (thus yielding the solution, `Ys = []`. It will then backtrack and find another solution: `Ys` is `[1]` and `_` is `[2,3]`. And so on...

So when you run your query, you get:

```
| ?- prefix([1,2,3], X).

X = [] ? ;          % append([], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]); X = [], _ = [1,2,3]

X = [1] ? ;         % append([1], [2,3], [1,2,3]); X = [1], _ = [2,3]

X = [1,2] ? ;       % append([1,2], [3], [1,2,3]); X = [1,2], _ = [3]

X = [1,2,3]         % append([1,2,3], [], [1,2,3]); X = [1,2,3], _ = []
```

Remember, Prolog seeks to find solutions by checking facts and rules and instantiating variables. If there's more than one way to instantiate the variables, it will backtrack. If backtracking finds another set of variable instantiations that makes the query true, Prolog will show it as a solution. If more backtracking is available, it prompts you for more (and entering `;` says to give me the next one).

Comment: why have you changed the order  of Xs and Ys in append(Ys, _, Xs).?

Comment: @Shiran Because that's the way append works. You are looking for a list (`Ys`) which when appended to another list (`_`) yields your given list `Xs`. In `append`, based upon how you defined how you want `prefix(Xs, Ys)` to work, `Xs` must be the result of the append operation, and `Ys` must be the first list being appended. Therefore, they are reverse order. The example description I gave illustrates that. I could do `prefix(Xs, Ys) :- append(Xs, _, Ys).`, but then I'd have to query as, `prefix(X, [1,2,3]).` which is not the way you asked for it to work.